# Stop msbuild process if a target fails

Tags: msbuild

Let's say I have three targets A, B and C. 
C depends on B.
B depends on A.
If I run `msbuild /t:C mybuildfile.xml`, it will execute target A, B and C in order. 
How do I set up to make sure C and B won't get executed if there is anything failed in A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<Target Name="StopBuild">
    <Message Text="An error has occurred, build stopped." />
</Target>

<Target Name="A">
    <OnError ExecuteTargets="StopBuild"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="B" DependsOnTargets="A">

</Target>
```

Ok, I figured out this by myself. Use the code above, if target A fails, it will go to StopBuild specified in OnError task. For more on how msbuild handles errors, go to 
http://en.csharp-online.net/MSBuild:_By_Example%E2%80%94Dealing_with_MSBuild_Errors

Comment: Sadly, the link appears to be broken now.