# Can I use StopOnFirstFailure to halt building of an sln file with MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, target

We build our solution using `msbuild` 4.0 from TeamCity. Our continuous build uses up quite a lot of resources, both on the build machine, and on our central signing and obfuscation servers. One thing I've noticed is that even when a project fails to compile, the build continues, and other projects that do compile get signed and obfuscated.

Is there some way to make the build halt as soon as something fails?

The [MsBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z7f65y0d.aspx) task actually supports a parameter `StopOnFirstFailure`. However, I can't seem to get it to have any effect.

Can I use this feature to do what I need? I'm prepared to edit e.g. the Microsoft.Common.Targets file on the build servers.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5312401/738851) answer on StackOverflow that involves emitting a `proj` file from the solution and then editing it. I guess I could automate that process on our build servers, but it seems a lot of work to achieve a fairly basic requirement.