# ASP.NET MSBuild Custom Task Before Publish Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, publish

I am maintaining my user displayed application version numbers in an app.ver file that is deployed with my ASP.NET web app.  Before publishing the application, I would like to be able to increment the version number in that file.

How can I hook into MSBuild to run a task that would do this incrementing prior to publishing?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899650/why-does-msbuild-ignore-my-beforepublish-target

Answer (score 0):

In your web project, add a [Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx) that executes prior to the Publish target using the BeforeTargets target attribute.

```
<Target Name="PrePublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
    ...
</Target>
```

Comment: I tried this.  Both BeforeTargets Publish and MSDeployPublish at the end of the .csproj file, neither seem to get called..

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx)

```
<Project>  
    ...  
    <Target Name="BeforePublish">  
        <!-- Insert tasks to run before publish here -->  
    </Target>  
    <Target Name="AfterPublish">  
        <!-- Insert tasks to run after publish here -->  
    </Target>  
</Project>
```